# Java CSS fx-focus-color not showing up in autocomplete list?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am currently trying to remove the focus color from a text area in my JavaFX application using CSS, however, it doesn't appear to be in the autocomplete list of styles that I can use. Why might this be?[Autocomplete list without -fx-focus-color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYTF8.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#scrollpane) for the list of supported styles you can use.

In JavaFX, `focused` is a pseudoclass. Therefore you should do something similar to this:

```
.ingredients:focused {
    -fx-background-color: transparent; /* Or the color when not focused */
}
```